# Camera calibration across multiple images

Tags: c, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Taking one camera and moving it around to take two images of the same object, from a different viewpoint, one should be able to compute a matrix that relates these two scenes.  In OpenCV, how is this accomplished?

Comment: Have a look at the [`cv::calibrateCamera`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv-calibratecamera) documentation, perhaps that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If said object is a calibration pattern like the chessboard used by OpenCV, then the camera calibration routine mentioned by ChrisO would give you both the camera intrinsics (focal length, principal point, and lens distortion) as well as the camera extrinsics (where they are relatively in space).

If you have general object, then you need to establish a set of 2D correspondences which you can feed into [cvFindFundamentalMat](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findfundamentalmat). This finds the fundamental matrix which relates the two perspectives. Namely, for each point x in camera 1 and corresponding point x' in camera 2, x'Fx = 0. You can similarly find the epipoles, etc. This uses the 8 point algorithm which requires at least 8 point pairs of point correspondences.

You can get the correspondences either manually or with a robust feature extractor and matcher along the lines of MSER/Affine Harris + SIFT.

Comment: If using a calibration pattern like a chessboard, and I get the parameters for both images, how do you relate relate them to one another?  In the case of using 2 cameras simultaneously, rather than 2 images, how do you take the 2 matrices and know that point x' = Cx, for some constant C?

Comment: Unless the camera axes are aligned, there's no constant scaling that would suffice. However, you can find the [epipolar line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipolar_geometry#Epipolar_line) in camera B for any point P in camera A. The reason that this is a line is due to the fact that you can't tell depth of the point in A.

Comment: So in theory, if you could tell the depth at point x (say you had a depth camera as well), would it be possible to get a matrix where for each point x in A and x' in B, x = Mx', where M is some matrix that relates them?  This is what I am truly interested in.

Comment: I don't think a single matrix would do it for every point in general. If the scene is planar, then yes.

Comment: Even with the corresponding Z (3d depth) point for each pixel?  Intuitively, it seems like all the information is there. Thanks for your help, by the way.